# Remove certain characters from a string in a select statement

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a PostgreSQL database and I want to remove certain characters from the output string.

select * from Table;

Output:-

```
Imapct        com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select
Approvals     com.atlassian.servicedesk.approvals-plugin:sd-approvals
Satisfaction  com.atlassian.servicedesk:sd-request-feedback
Actual Date   com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:datetime
Flagged       com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multicheckboxes
```

I'm looking for the output as shown below:

```
Imapct         select  
Approvals      sd-approvals  
Satisfaction   sd-request-feedback  
Actual Date    datetime  
Flagged        multicheckboxes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a whole string?  If so, and the general rule is that you wish to keep the first word, plus the end of the next string after a colon, you could do:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  'Imapct        com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select',
  '\s+.*:',
  ' ',
  'g'
);
```

Otherwise, if these are 2 columns, you'd just use:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  'com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select',
  '.*:',
  '',
  'g'
);
```

This is a regular expression replacement function, that takes the string (or column) you want to affect, then you provide a pattern to match, then the string to replace it with, and the 'g' at the end is just a global flag.

Comment: Hi Brown,
Thank you for response. This is not working. In the table for all rows in second column the values are different I need the values after the "**:**".

Comment: Ah, so this is 2 columns.  You would just need to use `SELECT regexp_replace(
  col2name,
  '.*:',
  '',
  'g'
);`
where you replace col2name with whatever your column is called.  Put this in a SELECT query with your first column, so `SELECT col1, <function_above> FROM table;`